Why cyclic subgroup of $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ is achieved by some decomposition group?
Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension.
Let $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ be its Galois group.
For every cyclic subgroup $H$ of $\text{Gal}(L/K)$, why does there exists a prime $v$ of ring of integers of $K$ and a prime $w$ of $L$ above $v$ such that $H\cong \text{Gal}(L_w/K_v)$ , in other words, every cyclic sub extension appears as decomposition group for certain prime $v$ ?
If $H=\text{Gal}(L/K)$, from Chebotarev density theorem, there exists $v$ such that it splits completely in $L$, so it is ok.
If $\#H=n$ and $\#\text{Gal}(L/K)=m$, we should find $v$ such that it splits into $m/n$ primes in $L/K$.
But if $H$ is proper subgroup of $\text{Gal}(L/K)$, how Chebotarev density ensures the existence of $v$ ?

You can consider the prime ideals whose associated Frobenius generate $H$.

Let $G = {\rm Gal}(L/K)$. Chebotarev says each conjugacy class in $G$ is a conjugacy class of Frobenius elements at infinitely many primes in $L$.  Once one element in a conjugacy class in $G$ is a Frobenius element at some prime ideal $\mathfrak P$ in $L$, every other element in its conjugacy class is a Frobenius element at some prime in $L$ lying over the same prime in $K$ as  $\mathfrak P$ does, since $g{\rm Frob}_{\mathfrak P}(L/K)g^{-1} = {\rm Frob}_{g(\mathfrak P)}(L/K)$.
So if you pick a cyclic subgroup $H$ in $G$ and a generator $h$ of $H$, Chebotarev says $h$ is a Frobenius element at infinitely many primes in $L$. The subgroup generated by a Frobenius element at an unramified prime is the decomposition group at that prime, so $H$ is the decomposition group at infinitely many primes in $L$.

Do you have any idea of an answer to this question? Thanks!
